# Different between JSON_EXTRACT and JSON_QUERY in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I wonder what's the difference between JSON_EXTRACT and JSON_QUERY.
In the [Bigquery document](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/json_functions?hl=fa#json_query_or_json_value), they two share identical explanation and samples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JSON_QUERY()` was added later to be conformed with SQL Standard 2016 version of JSON Path that appears in ISO/IEC TR 19075-6:2017.

The difference between JSON_EXTRACT and JSON_QUERY is on how to handle field name with a dot inside, see example below

```sql
WITH data AS (SELECT """
{
  "a.x" : { "b" : "c" }
}
""" json)
SELECT JSON_QUERY(json, '$."a.x"'), JSON_EXTRACT(json, "$['a.x']")
FROM data;
```

Output:

```
+-----------+-----------+
|    f0_    |    f1_    |
+-----------+-----------+
| {"b":"c"} | {"b":"c"} |
+-----------+-----------+
```

Comment: that is because `JSON_VALUE` is equivalent of `JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR` while `JSON_QUERY` is equivalent of `JSON_EXTRACT`. So if you will compare relevant pairs result will be the same. I feel that the question is really about what is the difference between those two pairs - `JSON_VALUE`, `JSON_QUERY` and `JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR`, `JSON_EXTRACT`? why those two new functions are introduced if they are exactly the same as long existing already ones?

Comment: You know me well :) that is exactly my question, why those two new functions are introduced if they are exactly the same as long existing already ones?

Comment: Oops... I misread the question. Updated my answer (also what's in the answer should be in public documentation, I'll look into how it should be updated)