# Why is JSON_EXTRACT in BigQuery deprecated?

Tags: google-bigquery

I was reading the BigQuery docs and I noticed `JSON_EXTRACT` was deprecated.

What the reason why and if there was a difference between `JSON_QUERY`

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/json_functions

Comment: hi @Kenneth Truong, If my answer addressed your question, do consider accepting and upvoting it as per [Stack Overflow guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), helping more Stack contributors with their researches.. If not, let me know so that I can improve my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/json_functions#function_list), `JSON_QUERY()` and `JSON_EXTRACT()` do the same work. JSON_QUERY was added later to be conformed with the SQL Standard 2016 version of JSON Path that appears in ISO/IEC TR 19075-6:2017 as mentioned in this [stack link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63353862/18329678).

As both the functions are equivalent to each other, you can use the **JSON_QUERY** instead of the JSON_EXTRACT(deprecated).

Comment: ahh thanks for the stack link! So the syntax is slightly different

Comment: I'm looking to extract strings, and had been using JSON_EXTRACT followed by REPLACE to get rid of the double quotes. JSON_VALUE is surely a lot nicer to read. Are these standard extractors also faster?